# How to have control over the user in node app, via IP address or over the id from the database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io

I write a chat application in nodejs with a socket.io library, the problem is in the administration of users, is it better to write an administrative logic based on clients ip adress or based on an id-s from the database?
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *is it better to write an administrative logic based on clients ip* but IP addresses change so you would need method to authenticate users and identify administrators.

Comment: Thanks Wayne Phipps,i cant upvote because of low reputation.So best way is to make DB based administration.

Comment: No problem, I've added it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it better to write an administrative logic based on clients ip

Most users will connect from a dynamic IP addresses so the IP address they use will most likely change.

You would need some method to authenticate users and identify administrators, normally using some user database.